# Inconsistent java.sql.Timestamp persistence to SQL server with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

My program is querying an SQL database with a DATETIME field called 'Measurement Time', below is related code in my model object. I am using hibernate.

```
private Timestamp measurementTime;

@Basic
@Column(name = "`Measurement Time`")
public Timestamp getMeasurementTime() {
    return measurementTime;
}

public void setMeasurementTime(Timestamp measurementTime) {
    this.measurementTime = measurementTime;
}
}
```

I select around 300,000 rows which I have in a list. When looping though them and printing the date as so:

```
System.out.println(obj.getMeasurementTime());
```

I get a lot of identical datetimes, perhaps 95% of the datetimes are identical. This does not match with the dataset.

I wondered what could be the problem here as it doesn't seem to make sense. The persistence? The driver hibernate is using?

```
private List<ResultsEntity> getResults(){

    Integer days ago = 365;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, - days_ago);

    Timestamp oneYearAgo =  new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    System.out.println(days_ago + " days ago: "+ oneYearAgo);

    List<ResultsEntity> ResultsEntityArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper();

    Session session = databaseHelper.getSession();

    Query query;

    try{
        query = session.createQuery(" from ResultsEntity where measurementTime > :time " +
                "and transmissionStatus != :status " +
                "and analyte like :analyteFilter and unit = :unit");
        query.setParameter("time", oneYearAgo);
        query.setParameter("status", "error");
        query.setParameter("analyteFilter","Gel%");
        query.setParameter("unit","m/L");

        ResultsEntityArrayList = query.list();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return ResultsEntityArrayList;
}
```

Comment: please add your query that is used to select those records.

Comment: See query added

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an obvious problem here. Have you tried looking at the data in the database through the command line to see if the data is bad? If the data in it matches-up to what Hibernate tells you, then the problem comes from somewhere else. Maybe the field was added later in development with a default value?

Comment: I have noticed that the column I assigned @Id to is not a primary key despite being called id, the majority of id values are empty! The is no primary key on the view I am using so not sure what to use instead. Could this explain the behaviour?